# Get gitdir if a filename is in a git repository

Tags: git

I have a script that need to check if a file was committed. The filename is the first argument of the script.
I know that i can get gitdir with command like this:

```
gitdir=$(cd $(dirname $filename) && git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null)
```

but is there another method to get the gitdir without first cd in the directory ?

Answer (score 0):

git relies on the current directory where it is ran, so it's not possible. I tried to run your command without `cd`ing in the directory and using `--work-tree=<dir>` option, but it didn't work.

So it looks like there's no other way than running it with the current directory being the working copy's directory.